# On a final project of residential automation, where should I put my Arduino?

Tags: home-automation

In a final project, where should I put my Arduino board and it's relay modules cases?

Maybe should I do an electric panel only for this purpose, or have other most simple solution?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Is there AC mains going to this stuff? You need to use certified equipment for switching AC mains, not hobby/electronics relays whose rating might cover AC voltage ranges.  (e.g. UL Listed, not RU Recognized). Alternately you can use approved smart modules that you communicate with wirelessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum you'll need to make sure that all your low-voltage Arduino related stuff is physically isolated from the 'real' high-voltage mains stuff, and mounted into its own separate box.
Then, depending on where in the world you are, you'll probably also need to ensure that any connections you make to the mains are through 'listed' modules - for example [relays like these](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B000LESCI2?tag=amz-mkt-chr-us-20&ascsubtag=1ba00-01000-org00-win10-other-smile-us000-pcomp-feature-pcomp-wm-8&ref=aa_pcomp_patf1).
Wiring mains directly into your own home-brew electronics is likely to be against the electrical code in force wherever you are, and will almost certainly void your insurance coverage if it's found to be the cause of a fire.

Answer (score 1):

In a project box, on or in a wall. Like an alarm system or other low-voltage gear.